# Wo zieht man Brillen an?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Mir kommt es unpassend vor, das Verb „anziehen“ für Uhren oder Brillen zu verwenden, aber ich kenne Leute, die das tun. Ist dies regional ein üblicher Gebrauch, und wenn ja, wo?

*Um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden: Ich beziehe mich auf das Anlegen von Uhren und Aufsetzen von Brillen.*

Comment: anekdotisch: Ich komme aus dem Südwesten und ziehe meine Brille *auf*, aber *lege* die Uhr an.

Comment: @Vogel612, ich kenne Uhren, die man aufziehen muss :)

Comment: @CarstenS: "uhren anziehen" kenne ich nicht. typischerweise "zieht man alte uhren auf". also "uhren aufziehen".

Comment: Im Schweizerdeutschen: *ich zieh mini Uhr/mini Brüle a* oder *Ich leg mini Uhr/Brüle a* - Deutsch verwendet üblicherweise *aufsetzen*, was im Schweizerdeutschen nicht verwendet wird.

Comment: @RalphM.Rickenbach... mach doch ne Antwort draus.

Comment: Mir kommt "anziehen" absolut natürlich vor. Da ich keine Uhr trage, kann ich nicht wirklich sagen, was ich sagen würde, aber spontan fällt mir gar keine Alternative zu "anziehen" ein. "Anlegen" finde ich unnatürlich, obwohl ich es schon mal gehört habe. Was die Brille angeht, trage ich tatsächlich eine, und verwende "anziehen". Ich komme aus dem Raum Köln, aber ob das für die ganze Region gilt oder nur für die Ecke, wo ich wohne, kann ich nicht sagen.

Comment: @Em1, ich habe mal die Brillen in die Überschrift genommen, da sie wahrscheinlich das bessere Beispiel abgeben. Eine Uhr „anzulegen“ finde ich zwar die richtige Wortwahl, aber was ich im Gespräch benutzen würde, weiß ich gar nicht, aber sicher nicht „anziehen“. Ich glaube, „ummachen“ käme mir als erstes in den Sinn und dann auch aus dem Mund, wenn ich mich nicht stoppe. Meine Brille setze ich aber definitiv auf.

Comment: Ich ziehe meine Brille morgens an, abend aus, habe sie tagsüber an und nachts habe ich sie nicht an. "Aufsetzen" wäre niemals meine Wortwahl, es klingt aber auch nicht ungewohnt. Es klingt eher sehr formal. Zu formal, als dass ich es angebracht fände zu verwenden. – "Ummachen" für die Uhr klingt noch schlimmer als "anlegen". – Der Link von Ingmar bestätigt auf jeden Fall, dass ich mich nicht irre. Es ist tasächlich der Raum südlich von Köln, wo man das so sagt, also dort wo ich wohne.

Comment: Ich ziehe Brillen an, im Auto, im Schlafzimmer, im Bad und im 3-D-Kino.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Anziehen* kann man mE nur Kleidungsstücke (Hemden, Leibchen, Hosen, Unterwäsche, Röcke, Kleider, Jacken, auch Schuhe und Handschuhe). Brillen (und Kopfbedeckungen) *setzt man auf*, alles andere klingt für mich (Ostösterreich) unidiomatisch. Bei Armbanduhren müsste ich nachdenken, aber *anziehen* geht auch hier gar nicht.

Im Westen und vor allem Südwesten Deutschlands ist der Ausdruck aber scheinbar nicht unüblich: https://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_3/f06c/

Und natürlich hat der Zwiebelfisch auch etwas dazu zu sagen: http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/gesellschaft/zwiebelfisch-ziehen-sie-die-brille-aus-a-718488.html

Comment: Ah, Danke, im Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache hätte ich selbst suchen sollen. Danke auch für "Leibchen", dazu müsste ich glatt auch noch eine Frage stellen ;)

Comment: Kann das nur bestätigen. Das Verb »anziehen« wird in Österreich nur für Kleidungsstücke verwendet, in die man mit einem Teil des Körpers hineinschlüpft. Es kann (in Österreich) nicht verwendet werden für: Hut/Haube/Mütze/Kappe (aufsetzen), Armbanduhr (anlegen), Gürtel (umbinden), Krawatte (umbinden), Schal (umlegen), Brille (aufsetzen).

Comment: Dein Link ist weniger hübsch, aber Du warst schneller ;)

Answer (score 14):

Brillen werden im größten Teil Deutschlands aufgesetzt, wie man anhand der folgenden Grafik sehr schön sehen kann.

[image]
*Quelle: [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache - Brille aufsetzen](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f06c/)*

Im wilden (Süd-)Westen werden sie jedoch vereinzelt bis ausschließlich angezogen und die Schweizer scheinen noch eins drauflegen zu müssen, indem Sie ihre Brillen wie Gewehre anlegen.

---

Zu den Uhren gibt es in besagtem Atlas bisher nur etwas bzgl. des Momentes nach dem anziehen/anlegen.

[image]
*Quelle: [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache - Uhr anhaben](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f06b/)*

Da scheint es ein Nordost-Südwest-Gefälle zu geben. Die einen haben ihre Uhre um und die anderen haben sie an.

Wenn man sie um hat, dann muss man sie vorher drum gemacht bzw. um den Arm gemacht haben. Wenn man sie aber an hat, dann muss sie wahrscheinlich angezogen oder angelegt worden sein. Hier gibt es also keinen Aufschluss über die Beschreibung des dem Tragen vorangegangene Prozedere.

Comment: Ich komm aus der Nähe von Stuttgart und ja, ich ziehe meine Brille an/aus und habe meine Uhr an/aus.  Typischer Satz: "Warte auf mich! Ich muss noch meine Sonnenbrille anziehen." Mein Optiker in Berlin sagt aber: "Bitte setzen Sie die Brille ab."

Comment: Ein Uhr __haben klingt für mich (Wien) in jedem Fall falsch. Ich *trage* eine Uhr, ich lege die Uhr an und nehme sie ab.

Comment: Man sieht aber auch ganz gut, dass Österreich, gerade auch die Region um Wien, eher spärlich vertreten ist. Wie repräsentativ das dann für diese Region ist, sei mal dahingestellt.
Ich finde, dass man eine Uhr anhaben kann, genauso wie man sie umhaben kann. Aber ja, wenn ich eine Uhr an-/umhabe, dann trage ich sie.

Comment: @PH13: Das dürfte einfach nur die geringe Bevölkerungsdichte widerspiegeln. Selbst die Schweiz hat auf halber Fläche mehr Einwohner als Österreich, beide Alpenländer zusammen weniger als Nordrhein-Westfalen. Auch in Deutschland kann man mit den Atlasdaten über einzelne Regionen nur dann Aussagen treffen, wenn sie in einem großen homogenen Bereich liegen.

Comment: @PH13: Innerhalb Österreichs scheint mir Wien tatsächlich unterrepräsentiert zu sein. Das könnte methodische Gründe haben: Nach meinem Eindruck von ein paar Jahren in Wien schätze ich, dass die wenigsten Einwohner der Stadt die Voraussetzungen für eine Teilnahme erfüllen. Wegen des überproportionalen Einflusses von Wienerisch auf das restliche Österreich dürfte das aber für das beabsichtigte Gesamtbild nicht so dramatisch sein.

Comment: Als Südwestdeutscher kann ich bestätigen, dass ich meine Brille aufsetze und sie danach aufhabe, aber meine Uhr anziehe und sie danach anhabe. Nicht weit von meiner Herkunftsregion scheinen sich Leute die Brille anzuziehen. Dennoch kommt es mir schlicht falsch vor. Anders als das norddeutsche Umlegen und Umhaben von Uhren, das für mich eher formal und fremd aber trotzdem eindeutig auch richtig klingt.

Answer (score 4):

Im Schweizerdeutschen wird *anziehen* sowohl für Uhren als auch Brillen verwendet. Da heisst es z.B. im Zürichdeutschen:

> Ich zië mini Uhr/mini Brüle a.

Alternativ wird auch gesagt

> Ich leg mini Uhr/mini Brüle a.

Eine Brille wird üblicherweise nicht aufgesetzt im Schweizerdeutschen, das tönt aufgesetzt.

Das gleiche gilt z.B. für Hüte

> Ich zië/leg en Huët a.

Schweizer würden das alles wohl auch auf "Hochdeutsch" so verwenden - und sich so vielleicht zu erkennen geben.

Answer (score 2):

In Ostdeutschland *setzt* man die Brille *auf* und *macht* sich eine Uhr *um* oder *dran*. Das "Gemache" bei Zweiterem wäre glaube auch niemandem peinlich (wie es Carsten in seinem Kommentar zu seiner Frage zu sein scheint ;) ).

Sprecher die diese Dinge anziehen oder anlegen würde ich intuitiv als DaF-Sprecher, Zeitreisende oder Linguistiknerds identifizieren.

Comment: Das entspricht im wesentlichen dem, was ich auch kenne. Ich komme auch Berlin, und das liegt ja im Osten.